# Solving differential equation using RK4 is 5 times faster with Fortran than with C++

Tags: c++, performance, differential-equations

Why does my Fortran code execute 5 times faster than my C++ code to solve this second order differential equation (for universal gravitation between a planet and a sun) using RK4?
How could I optimize my C++ code, please ?

I have tried changing pow() to x*x with no improvements. Removing the write operations divided execution time by 2 on Fortran, but only made C++ code about 15% faster.

Here are the codes:

C++ (compiled with: c++ -Wall -Wextra equadiff.cpp -o equadiffcpp.x):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<cmath>
#include <chrono> //pour mesurer le temps d'execution

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

void deriv(double t, double X[], double Xderiv[], int n){
double radius;
radius=sqrt(pow(X[0],2)+pow(X[1],2));
Xderiv[0]=X[2];
Xderiv[1]=X[3];
Xderiv[2]=-X[0]/pow(radius,3);
Xderiv[3]=-X[1]/pow(radius,3);
}



void rk4(double t, double X[], double dt, int n, void deriv(double, double[], double[], int)){

int i;
double ddt;
double Xp[n], k1[n], k2[n], k3[n], k4[n];
ddt=0.5*dt;

deriv(t,X,k1,n);

for(i=0;i<n;i++){
Xp[i]=X[i]+ddt*k1[i];
deriv(t+ddt,Xp,k2,n);
}

for(i=0;i<n;i++){
Xp[i]=X[i]+ddt*k2[i];
deriv(t+ddt,Xp,k3,n);
}

for(i=0;i<n;i++){
Xp[i]=X[i]+dt*k3[i];
deriv(t+dt,Xp,k4,n);
}

for(i=0;i<n;i++){
X[i] = X[i] + dt*(k1[i]+2*k2[i]+2*k3[i]+k4[i])/6;
}
}


int main(void){
double dt, t, tmax;
double X[4];
double Xderiv[4];

dt=0.01;
tmax=1000.0;

X[0]=1.0;
X[1]=0.0;
X[2]=0.0;
X[3]=-0.5;

ofstream fichier ("equadiffrk4cpp.out");

auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();//on commence a compter le temps de mesure

for(t=0.0;t<=tmax;t+=dt){
    rk4(t,X,dt,4,deriv);
    if((int)(round(t/dt))%10==0){//on n'ecrit qu'une valeur sur 10
    fichier <<t<<" "<<X[0]<<" "<<X[1]<<endl;
    }
}

auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();//on arrete de compter le temps d'execution

fichier.close();

auto duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(stop - start); 
  
cout << "Time taken by function: "
         << duration.count() << " microseconds" << endl; 
  
return 0; 

}
```

Fortran90 (compiled with: gfortran equadiff.f90 -o equadifff90.x):

```
program  meca_planet
implicit none
real (8) :: dt ,t
integer  :: i
real(8),  dimension (4) :: X, Xderiv
external  :: euler, deriv_planet, rk4

real :: start, finish!pour compter temps execution du programme

t=0.
dt=0.01

!Initialization
X=(/1.,0.,0.,-0.5/)

open(11,file='equadiffrk4f90.out')

call cpu_time(start)!on commence a compter

do i=1,100000!tmax=0.01*100000=1000
    t=t+dt
    call  rk4(t,X,dt,4,deriv_planet)
    if (mod(nint(t/dt),10).eq.0) then
        write(11,*) t, X(1),X(2)
    endif
enddo

call cpu_time(finish)!on arrete de compter

close (11)

print '("Time = ",f6.3," seconds.")',finish-start

end program meca_planet

subroutine deriv_planet(t,X,Xderiv,n)
implicit none
integer, intent(in) :: n
real(8), intent (in) :: t!pourquoi on definit t dans deriv_planet mais ensuite on ne l'utilise pas?
real(8) :: radius
real(8), dimension(n), intent(in) :: X
real(8), dimension(n), intent(out) :: Xderiv
if (n.ne.4) write (*,*) 'WARNING: dimension de n incorrecte, devrait etre 4'
radius=sqrt(X(1)**2+X(2)**2)
Xderiv(1)=X(3)
Xderiv(2)=X(4)
Xderiv(3)=-X(1)/radius**3
Xderiv(4)=-X(2)/radius**3
end subroutine deriv_planet

subroutine rk4(t,X,dt,n,deriv)
!Runge-Kutta du 4eme ordre
implicit none
integer, intent(in) :: n
real(8), intent(in) :: t, dt
real(8), dimension(n), intent (inout) :: X
real(8) :: ddt
real(8), dimension(n) :: Xp, k1, k2, k3, k4
ddt = 0.5*dt
call deriv(t,X,k1,n); Xp=X+ddt*k1
call deriv(t+ddt,Xp,k2,n); Xp=X+ddt*k2
call deriv(t+ddt,Xp,k3,n); Xp=X+dt*k3
call deriv(t+dt,Xp,k4,n); X = X + dt*(k1+2.0*k2 + 2.0*k3+k4)/6.0
end subroutine rk4
```

The end goal is to code an N-body problem for a solar system, and then perhaps a galaxy. I was thinking of using C++ but based on this initial assessment I am now leaning towards Fortran90.

Comment: Drastic performance failures are usually the result of compiling without turning on optimizations.

Comment: which C++ compiier? What options are passed to compiler?

Comment: Thanks for your questions! c++ -Wall -Wextra equadiff.cpp -o equadiffcpp.x // gfortran equadiff.f90 -o equadifff90.x . I edited my post to add the info.

Comment: @Tommy95 Turn on optimizations. Try with `-O3`.

Comment: I compiled with: c++ -Wall -Wextra equadiff.cpp -o equadiffcpp.x -O3, is that what you had in mind?

Comment: Do not use `std::endl` for newlines, it flushes the whole stream which is slow. Just use `'\n'`.

Comment: Compiling with: c++ -Wall -Wextra equadiff.cpp -o equadiffcpp.x -O3 went me go down from 0.3 seconds to 0.2, which is great but still about 4 times longer than Fortran right now

Comment: Does not matter for speed, but your literal floating point constants in the Fortran code have only 24 bits of precision (on most modern hardware).  Fortunately, for you the literal constants are exactly representable in both 24 bits and 53 bits, so using the likely wrong precision does not hurt you.

Comment: Thanks Quimby, we're just under 0.20 seconds now with '\n', your addition made me win 0.03 seconds

Comment: @Tommy95 Nice :) I mean it more like a general advice. Another thing - `k4[n];` is not valid C++, gcc supports VLAs as extensions but no idea how performant they are. Try using compile-time value or just hardcode `4` there for the benchmark. Maybe it can have some impact.

Comment: Whoops. Didn't see `dt = 0.01`.  Double whoops.  You don't want to increment time by `t = t + dt`.

Comment: In general, it is a lot easier to write a high-performance program in Fortran than in C/C++ and a lot easier for the compiler to optimize a Fortran program than a C++ program. But a carefully-written C++ program should have similar performance to the Fortran equivalent. The question then becomes how much learning C++ and the development of that "carefully-written" C++ program takes compared to learning Fortran and writing the concept in Fortran. If you go with Fortran, learn Fortran 2018 or at least 2008. Both the syntax and feature sets are drastically richer in Fortran 2003 / 2008 / 2018.

Comment: Hey Steve, thanks for raising this but what's the issue with doing t=t+0.01?

Comment: Quimby, sorry I am no expert here, you mean you would change the way I define my variable k4, and all the others I define similarly? Concretely, how would you define them instead, please?

Comment: Try `-Ofast` as well. A large part of the CPU time is spent on I/O by the way, just try writing less often (use `% 100`) and the time spent drastically reduces. Last but not least, your code only runs for tens of milliseconds on a fast CPU, try increasing the amount of computations you do or add an outer loop to your code, otherwise cache effects, CPU frequency scaling and process scheduling issues will have a large effect on the timing.

Comment: You may want to try out different compilers (for example, sometimes Intel's icc profits from targeting just x86 and Intel's expertise, I think). But typically, with float computation-heavy programs there is only so much optimization possible; there is no way around the actual computation. But: Did you check whether the Fortran compiler uses CPU features like SEE/AVX on doubles? Try `-march=native`with gcc, perhaps that helps exploiting your CPU's capabilities.

Comment: My Fortran and math memories are rusty at best (if not expired), but are those programs doing the same calculations? In the C++ snippet `deriv` is called multiple times in each loop, while in the Fortran one there seems to be a single call before any array update.

Comment: Using microsoft cl the compile for speed option /O2 shaves about 25% off. Other tweaks that might produce a small difference 1) Using pre-increment rather than post increment in your rk4 loops. 2) function parameter n not used in deriv, drop. 3) as mentioned by @Quimby your array initialisations with non-const n in rk4 isn't legal C++ so you can hard code and drop parameter n from rk4 too, loops max on 4 instead of n. 4) dropping rk4 parameter deriv as it can be reached as a global.

Comment: I run a small [benchmark](https://quick-bench.com/q/a9zwpAQ79t8uLdl5e_3I2tj0dEk) and replacing `pow` seem to matter a lot, VLAs are not an issue, still you should not rely on them because they are not portable. As someone else said, foor loops with doubles are just wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment of Bob__'s should capture the main culprit: In your loops you call `deriv` after the update of each coordinate. But only the last call counts. As that is done with the completely set vector, you get overall the correct result. Change to

```cpp
for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
  Xp[i]=X[i]+ddt*k1[i];
}
deriv(t+ddt,Xp,k2,n);
```

etc. and the time should reduce by a factor of about 3, replacing `3*4+1=13` `deriv` calls with just 4.

---

You can reduce the root computation by a square root. Just compute

```cpp
r3 = pow(X[0]*X[0]+X[1]*X[1], 1.5);
```

Perhaps also replace the division by a multiplication using

```cpp
ir3 = pow(X[0]*X[0]+X[1]*X[1], -1.5);
```

---

It is an impractical idea to simulate even a large solar system with RK4. You get too many different scales, processes at largely different frequencies. Also, bodies on an significantly excentric orbit will move very slowly at their far point and very quickly at their nearest point, which is poorly captured with a fixed step size. It is better to use solvers with adaptive step sizes, possibly even using separate solvers for inner system, outer system and comets that are connected via their "dense output" interpolations. Look up the ["Moving stars around"](http://www.artcompsci.org/msa/web/vol_1/v1_web/v1_web.html) tutorial, in the end they give some starting ideas how large scale celestial simulations are organized.

Comment: Indeed! Thanks a lot to you and to Bob. I have also implemented as many of the other comments as possible. Your suggested pow lines actually increase the execution time of the code on my device. You guys made my execution time go from 0.30 seconds to 0.03 seconds! And thanks a lot for the link, I started reading it, this will definitely be useful!